# Excel - "File Not Found: VBA6.DLL"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2007 Sheet with Macros. When I click on a button, it immediately pops up an error "File Not Found: VBA6.DLL"

Problem is, I have been using this sheet forever, and never seen this problem before. I did make some very very minor changes to the Macro code.

And, I have 2 other sheets with identical macro code which I made the same changes to. And those two sheets run fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this order:

- Check your references (Alt+F11, Tools-References) to see if any are marked MISSING and make sure that Visual Basic for Applicatiions is checked.
- Check the directory C:\WINDOWS\system32 for VBA6.dll
- You may need to register VBA6.dll (Start->Run)

  Regsvr32.EXE "C:\WINDOWS\system32\VBA6.dll"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a shared file.  The fix was as follows:

1. Un-share the file
2. Copy all macros; sheets, this workbook, modules and saved them in a text format.
3. Save the .xlsm as a .xlsx file
4. Save back to .xlxm file
5. Paste all macros back in
6. Reset shortcut keys and descriptions in macro options
7. Re-share the file

This worked without having to go to IT and get someone with administrative credentials to fix it.